# How to replace specific text at the beginning of a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, sql-update

I am trying to **replace specific text** from **all the occurrence** from a field in mysql.

I have following data in **code** field.

**Code**

---

> hello12
>
> 12hello
>
> 12hel12
>
> 1212hi1

---

**i want following output**

> hello
>
> hel12
>
> 12hi1

---

**I have tried following code**

```
UPDATE code_table
SET code = REPLACE(code, '12', '')
```

**Output**

> hello
>
> hello
>
> hel
>
> hi1

I have also tried this code

```
UPDATE code_table
    SET code = REPLACE(code, '12', '')
    where code regexp ('^12')
```

But i am getting following **output**

> hello
>
> hel
>
> hi1

This is expected because where clause only check whether data has **12** at the beginning of string and replace **all occurrence of 12** from the  string.

Is there any way to use **regexp** inside **replace** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the record with the 12 prefix, then just replace the record with substring:

`update code_table set code =  substring(code, locate("12", code)+length("12"))  where code regexp '^12';`

Comment: be mindful that using `WHERE code LIKE '12%'` is more efficient than **regexp**